How to achieve reliable monitoring of wireguard server?
I have configured Wireguard on a VPS that serves as a VPN server that allows access to my company's private network. The configuration is placed under /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf and VPN is launched with command systemctl enable --now wg-quick@wg0.
I would like to create reliable monitoring of this VPN using Prometheus to know if the interface wg0 is up and every peer is able to successfully connect anytime.
I wanted to use wireguard_exporter. However my only idea is to rely on wireguard_latest_handshake_seconds metric. But what if there are no active peers? I do not want Prometheus alert to be active then

How can the server know why an peer isn't active?

@vidarlo I thought of using PeristentKeepAlive option so some data is continuously sent

That doesn't tell you why.

you state you want to know if every peer is able to successfully connect anytime, but just because a peer is not connected doesn't mean it is not able to connect. Therefore, how can you check if a peer is able to connect

@vidarlo Maybe I didn't phrase the question precisely. I don't need to know why; let's assume that two VPSs are constantly exchanging some information using WireGuard. Now, I would like to receive a notification from Alertmanager, for example, on Slack, with the message "Something is wrong with the WireGuard." This is the state I want to achieve.
